# How to detect the iPhone is falling down or moving upwards in Objective-C or Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, accelerometer

How to detect the device is falling down or moving upwards in Objective-C or Swift? The Core Motion only detect the movement when we tilt the device I need to detect the free fall of the device. Is there any relevant sensors calculating the falling speed of the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple iPhone 6 has integrated [barometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer) sensor so this might be the sensor that you are looking for. To access barometer data you will need to use [CMAltimeter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltimeter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAltimeter) and [CMAltitudeData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAltitudeData_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAltitudeData) classes